# ViewPagerIndicator doesn't show titles

Tags: android, android-fragments, viewpagerindicator

I would like to use ViewPagerIndicator for navigation through the fragments in my app. I have successfully imported the library and implemented the TitlePageIndicator. So far I don't have any exceptions when I start the application and I also see the Indicator but without any page names. Here is my code

**viewpager_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

 <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+android:id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**SearchActivity**

```
public class SearchActivity extends FragmentActivity 
implements Tab1Fragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener, Tab2Fragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener 
{

private MyPagerAdapter mPagerAdapter; 

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //getApplicationContext().deleteDatabase("db");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);

    UserID.getInstance().createUserID(this);

    this.initialisePaging(); //initialsie the pager
    invalidateOptionsMenu();

}

private void initialisePaging() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab1Fragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab2Fragment.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Tab3Fragment.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter  = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);


    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    TitlePageIndicator titleIndicator = (TitlePageIndicator) findViewById(R.id.titles);
    titleIndicator.setViewPager(pager);
}
}
```

**MyPagerAdapter**

```
package com.easyimmoandroid.myPager;

import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private static final String[] TITLES = new String[] { "Title 1", "Title 2",  "Title 3" };

private List<Fragment> fragments;

public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
    return this.fragments.get(pos);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return TITLES[position];
}

}
```

**Fragment**

```
package com.easyimmoandroid.fragments;

public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

private ScrollView mScrollView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        return null;
    }

    // FRAGMENT LAYOUT
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_frag1_layout,
            container, false);
...

return mScrollView;
}
```

thank you for your help

and as this still does't work, I would ask you to suggest me if there is any other solution to do this except with WiewPagerIndicator.

Comment: super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout); you can remove super

Comment: @amer.salkovic +1 to Raghunandan and also ViewPager pager = (ViewPager)super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);-what is this means?

Comment: I was using this http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/ tutorial to fragments and swiping. I have found it there. I think that activity should host viewpager_layout and this is the way how it should be done or am I wrong?

Comment: @ Pratik
ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager); it is a viewpager defined in viewpager_layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this at the end of your initialisePaging method:

```
        pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(position);
        }
    });
```

It worked for me :)

Comment: watching the site of titlepageindicator you should add this aswell `titleIndicator.setOnPageChangeListener(mPageChangeListener);` So create a listener object and set on both of them, not sure if it will work

Answer (score 0):

Change your `getItem()` method like this

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
        return TestFragment.newInstance(fragments.get(position % fragments.size));
    }
```

also change you `getPageTitle` method to

```
    @Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return MyPagerAdapter.fragments.get(position % fragments.size);
}
```

and the `TestFragment` class look like

```
        public final class TestFragment extends Fragment{


            static Typeface typeface, type2;
            private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "TestFragment:Content";



            public static TestFragment newInstance(String content)
            {

                TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                builder.append(content).append(" ");

                builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
                fragment.mContent = builder.toString();

                return fragment;
            }

            private String mContent = "???";

            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


                if ((savedInstanceState != null) && savedInstanceState.containsKey(KEY_CONTENT))
                {
                    mContent = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_CONTENT);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getActivity());

                layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));



     TextView text = new TextView(getActivity());
                text.setText(mContent);
                text.setTextSize(20f);
                layout.addView(text);
                layout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                return layout;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
            {
                super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
                outState.putString(KEY_CONTENT, mContent);
            }
}
```

Hope that it may solve your problem

Comment: TestFragment should be one of my fragments or?

Comment: Test fragment is the class which extends fragment

Comment: now the newInstance method is the problem. I don't have it in my fragments. is it a constructor or what?

Comment: I have imported also one of my fragments in the code abowe. Are you sure that I need to change all of that. I mean, the app used to work and still works fine without newInstance method. Is it necessary?